# How to set initial value in PersianDatePicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using [PersianDatePicker](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/) in a modal with ajax. I want to change the date of picker based on ajax response. What I did is:

```
$('.mydateclass').val('1399-12-12');
```

I also tried something like:

```
var pd = $('.selector').persianDatepicker();
pd.setDate(1382276091100)
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: this works fine for rangeSelector

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this problem.
You can use **value** attribute of input field and persianDatepicker will handle it. Like:

```html
<input type="text" name="myDate" value="2015-12-12" class="pwt-datepicker-input-element">
```